# Is it anyway possible to find the starting and ending geometric positions of the texts present in TextFiled in QML?

Tags: qt, qml, textfield

I want to highlight the current present text in `TextField` of QML as shown in the below added image. 
[image]

I know about `selectAll` but the problem with that is that when new texts are added, previous texts disappear. I know that probably with `TextEdit` and `TextArea` you can probably do that using `QQuickTextDocument` but with those two I don't have the option to restrict what input it will take using something something like this

```
validator: IntValidator { bottom:lowestInput; top: highestInput}
```

So, is there anyway I can highlight the text in `TextField` without selectAll?

Thanks.

Comment: I guess you can use [FontMetrics](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-fontmetrics.html#details) to get a text bounds

Comment: Could you please elaborate in your suggestion? @folibis

Answer (score 0):

When you use `selectAll`, it will work as if you have selected the text with the mouse. So, when the user will write something else, the selected text will be removed.

You need to highlight the text instead of select it.

Use the `QSyntaxHighlither` class and a `TextField` element to highlight a pattern.

First, you need to create a new class that inherits from `QSyntaxHighlighter` and redefine the method `highlightBlock()`.

You also have to create a new method which is invokable from QML. A `TextEdit` uses a `QQuickTextDocument` as text document. You need to get the `QTextDocument` in it:

```
class SyntaxHighlighter: public QSyntaxHighlighter
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    SyntaxHighlighter(QTextDocument* parent=nullptr): QSyntaxHighlighter(parent)
    {}

protected:
    void highlightBlock(const QString &text) override
    {
        QTextCharFormat format;
        format.setFontWeight(QFont::Bold);
        format.setForeground(Qt::white);
        format.setBackground(Qt::darkBlue);


        QString const pattern("PT 36631");
        int index = text.indexOf(pattern);
        while (index != -1)
        {
            setFormat(index, pattern.length(), format);
            index = text.indexOf(pattern, index + 1);
        }
    }

    Q_INVOKABLE void setDocument(QQuickTextDocument* document)
    {
        QSyntaxHighlighter::setDocument(document->textDocument());
    }
};
```

Then, set the highlighter as a new context property in your QML:

```
    SyntaxHighlighter* highlighter = new SyntaxHighlighter;

    QQuickView *view = new QQuickView;
    view->rootContext()->setContextProperty("highlighter", highlighter);
    view->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/main.qml"));

    view->show();
```

Now, you can use it in your `TextEdit`:

```
TextEdit {
    id: editor
    anchors.fill: parent
    Component.onCompleted: {
        highlighter.setDocument(editor.textDocument)
    }
}
```

If you only need to check if the input is an integer in a range, you could use the signal `textChanged` to validate the value.

A quick example:

```
TextEdit {
    id: editor
    anchors.fill: parent
    Component.onCompleted: {
        highlighter.setDocument(editor.textDocument)
    }

    QtObject {
        id: d
        property string validatedText: ""
    }

    onTextChanged: {
        var lowestInput = 0;
        var highestInput = 255;
        var integerOnly = parseInt(text);
        if (!integerOnly)
        {
            editor.text = d.validatedText
            return
        }
        if (integerOnly < lowestInput || integerOnly > highestInput)
        {
            editor.text = d.validatedText
            return
        }
        d.validatedText = editor.text
    }
}
```